# When use Class as a Type,can't use the static method of it

Tags: class, types, typescript

There are two Class:

```
class Observer {
    static Update(value) { }
}
class ObserverList {
    private observerList: Observer[];
    constructor() {
        this.observerList = [];
    }
    Get(index: number): Observer {
        if (index > -1 && index < this.observerList.length) {
            return this.observerList[index];
        }
    }
}
```

I use then like this:

```
var obList=new ObserverList();
obList.Get(3).Update();
```

And then waring me `Property 'Update' does not exist on Type Observer`。
Is this a wrong way to use Class Observer as a return type?

[image]

Comment: Which language is this? You might want to add a tag so more people would see this question.

Comment: @anatolyg, it's typescript.

Comment: If a method is `static`, that means it works without any connection to a specific object of that class. If your method actually does need to be `static`, then you have to call it directly on the class: `Observer.Update()`, not on an individual observer instance.

Comment: @DCoder Thanks for your answer, the method `Update()` doesn't need to be `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Observer.Update method as static.

Also in typescript, its good practice to mark observers method with type signature, like in following snippet:

```
class Observer {
    public Update(value: <yourParameterType>): void { }
}
```

If you have this Observer class, you can call Update method on it

```
obList.Get(3).Update();
```